# Only label for value "zero" is not centered to its tick in Plot()

Tags: r, plot, label

I am using normal `plot()` in R, and do the label and ticks with the pretty-function for more flexibility (marks...).

But it happens that the label for the value "zero" is not properly aligned (centred) around the corresponding tick, whereas all others are looking OK. (*See screenshots linked below.*)

- It only happens, when I use "scientific=FALSE" in format(...)
- It looks correct, if I use "scientific=TRUE"

It seems, that the zero is aligned to the right, instead of centered, and R is believing that the "zero" has the same amount of digits than the other big numbers (e.g. "100 000") and it aligns "000 000" centred instead of only "0".

Anything easy I can do?

Minimal Working Example:

```
plot(x=NULL, y=NULL, xlab="xlab", ylab="ylab"
      , xlim=range(2007:2014), ylim=range(0:500000), axes=FALSE)
      box()
      ticks_x <- pretty(2007:2014,n=6)
      ticks_y <- pretty(0:500000,n=8)

      labels_x <- format(ticks_x)
      labels_y <- format(ticks_y , big.mark = " " , decimal.mark=",", scientific=FALSE)

      axis(1, at = ticks_x, labels = labels_x)
      axis(2, at = ticks_y, labels = labels_y)
```

Screenshots:

[image]

[image]

Any suggestions how to "centre" the "zero", if no scientific-mode is used?

A manual solution with "inserting as text" or similar is not possible, because the plot is created inside a loop, and only sometimes the zero occurs, but then it is always wrong aligned.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Axis labels are character strings. Have a check at your current `labels_y`:

```
#[1] "      0" " 50 000" "100 000" "150 000" "200 000" "250 000" "300 000"
#[8] "350 000" "400 000" "450 000" "500 000"
```

You get the undesired alignment, simply because the labels for 0 is `"      0"`. The problem can be fixed by:

```
labels_y[1] <- "   0   "
## or simply: labels_y[1] <- "0"
axis(2, at = ticks_y, labels = labels_y)
```

[image]

Comment: Good point, they always have the same length (see 50k label). Is there a reason for that behavior? Perhaps it is helpful to always use `gsub("^\\s+|\\s+$", "", labels_y)` (Delete leading and tailing white spaces).

Comment: @ZheyuanLi: Yes, you got the point. Is there a way to remove "empty" spaces in the labels, thus make "-----0" --> "0"? ("-" stands for the empty spaces).

Comment: @Christoph: OK, I got your point. But then I have to introduce a if(...) case, to check IF there even is a "0". 
AND: I make a lot of plots within a loop. So I need to figure out how to automatize the recognition, if it should be "--0--" or "----0----" or "-0-".... Kind of unconfortable. Any other thoughts?

Comment: I managed it by introducing
if(as.numeric(labels_y[1]) == "0"){labels_y[1] <- "0"}
and it works! Thanks a lot!

BTW: Do you know a better way to play with the labels when I want nice scales (pretty), an option for "decimal.mark", and I still did not managed to make bigger "main" ticks with labels and smaller "intermediate" ticks without label...any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

**FINAL SOLUTION:**

Introducing ...

```
[...] 
    labels_y <- format(....
if(as.numeric(ticks_y[1]) == "0"){labels_y[1] <- "0"}
    axis(2,.... 
[...]
```

... between "labels_y <- ..." and "axis(..." does the trick!

Answer (score 0):

Just use `axis(2, at = ticks_y-50000, labels = labels_y)`. If you like to automate, you can use the par("usr") to shift according to range.

Comment: But you suggest to shift the complete labels and ticks by -50000. This is not my intention. The questions is, how to tell that all numbers (incl. "0", doesn't matter if displayd as "0" or "000000") are properly aligned and centered around their corresponding tick....